# AB Testing (Component Level) Variant Preview floating bar is disappearing after page load in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, personalization, content-testing

While doing component testing Variant `Preview floating bar` is disappearing after page load in `Experience Editor`. We are using `Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170728)`. Please let us know if anyone faced this issue and resolved it.
[image]

Comment: Anything in logs?

Comment: No Ahmed. No logs related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "Control bar" checkbox is ticked, this one is responsible to show/hide the A/B testing dropdown in the floating toolbar:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by Sitecore support, this issue seems to be known an issue and has been fixed in Sitecore 9.0 Initial Release, see the [Release Notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes), search for 110468. For Sitecore 8.2 update 5, they provided a patch to fix this issue and the patch can be found in the below URL.

https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.110468/releases